# Roots of a polynomial form

Tags: polynomials

After some derivations on a problem I am working on, I arrived at the following form of polynomials ($p\in \mathbb{N}$, $y\in[0,1]$): 
$$0=-px^{p+1}+(p+1)x^p-y$$
$$0=p(p+1)x^{p+2}-2p(p+2)x^{p+1}+(p+1)(p+2)x^p-2y$$
$$0=-p(p+1)(p+2)x^{p+3}+3p(p+1)(p+3)x^{p+2}-3p(p+2)(p+3)x^{p+1}+(p+1)(p+2)(p+3)x^p-6y$$
and in general:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k{n\choose k}{(p)_{n+1}\over p+k}x^{p+k}-n!y=0.$$
I was wondering if there is some literature on their roots?

Comment: What's wrong with factoring $x^p$?

Comment: Sorry, I made corrections to the formulation.

Answer (score 1):

For $y_1$ 0 is a root of multiplicity $p$ and $1+\frac{1}{p}$ is the other root of multiplicity 1, as you can get by simply factoring out $x^p$.

In exactly the same way for $y_2$ again 0 is a root of multiplicity $p$ and the other two roots you can get in a most straightforward manner from the quadratic formula